# Descargar un archivo de manera automática al terminar un contador con JS

Tags: javascript, html5

necesito ayuda con la descarga un archivo de manera automática con JavaScript
en la parte que dice D E S C A R G A R, en su lugar que me descargue un archivo... ¿Cómo se hace eso?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var seconds = 10; //número de segundos a contar
  function secondPassed() {

  var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60); //calcula el número de minutos
  var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60; //calcula los segundos
//si los segundos usan sólo un dígito, añadimos un cero a la izq
  if (remainingSeconds < 10) { 
   remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
  } 
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +     
  remainingSeconds; 
  if (seconds == 0) { 
  clearInterval(countdownTimer); 
 //alert('Listo para descargar'); 
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = " D E S C A R G A R "; 
  } else { 
  seconds--; 
  } 
 } 

  var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reemplaza esa linea:

```
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = " D E S C A R G A R ";
```

Por esta:

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = 'cualquier/ruta/archivo.ext';
anchor.target = '_blank';
anchor.download = 'archivo.ext'; //o el nombre que sea
anchor.click();
```

Lo que esta haciendo es crear dinamicamente una etiqueta `<a href="">Nombre</a>` 
para luego hacer click en ella

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Mira lo acabo de hacer de esta manera y ya me funciona...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function download(nombre, url) {
    var link= document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', url);
    link.setAttribute('download', nombre);
    link.click();
}

var seconds = 10; //número de segundos a contar
    function secondPassed() {

      var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60); //calcula el número de minutos
      var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60; //calcula los segundos
      //si los segundos usan sólo un dígito, añadimos un cero a la izq
      if (remainingSeconds < 10) { 
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
      } 
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +     remainingSeconds; 
      if (seconds == 0) { 
        clearInterval(countdownTimer); 
        //alert('Listo para descargar'); 
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = download('GuíaParaNoExpertosEnWIFI(ver 0.1).pdf', 'Proyecto-GFR/gpon-landing/download/gpnew.pdf').innerHTML = "Listo!";

      } else { 
        seconds--; 
      } 
    } 

    var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
 </script>
```